# Does Green's $\mathcal{J}$-relation define a total order on the equivalence classes?

Tags: order-theory, semigroups

In a semigroup $S$ we define $a\le_\mathcal{J} b$ iff $a=xby$ for some $x,y\in S^1$. Defining $a\equiv_\mathcal{J} b$ by $a\le_\mathcal{J} b$ and $b\le_\mathcal{J} a$ gives a partial order on $S/\equiv_\mathcal{J}$. Is this order always total?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No it is not always a total order.

For example, in the semigroup $S$ with elements $a$, $b$, and $c$ and multiplication in the table below:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
&a&b&c\\\hline
a&a&a&a\\
b&a&b&a\\
c&a&a&c
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

The $\mathscr{J}$-order on $S$ has $b$ and $c$ incomparable, $a\leq_{\mathscr{J}} b$ and $a\leq_{\mathscr{J}} c$.

More generally, every partially ordered set with a minimum element is order-isomorphic to the partial order of the $\mathscr{J}$-classes of some semigroup. A reference for this is Theorem 4(i) in the paper

> [C. J. Ash and T. E. Hall, Inverse semigroups on graphs, *Semigroup Forum* **11** (1975)
>   140–145.](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN362162808_0011&DMDID=DMDLOG_0016)

Answer (score 2):

It might be good to look at this order as the inclusion of principal two-sided ideals instead (as it's isomorphic). Perhaps the fact that you didn't look at it like this is why you didn't immediately answer the question yourself. By your nickname I assume you like rings. In rings, principal ideals in the ring-theoretic sense and principal ideals in the semigroup-theoretic sense are the exact same thing. In the commutative case, two-sided and one-sided principal ideals are the same thing too. Can you see examples of commutative rings you know in which the principal ideals don't form a chain?

Comment: For example in Z. For $p$ prime the ideals $(p)$ are incomparable.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Yes, actually you might try asking yourself the opposite question: what commutative rings can you name in which principal ideals form a chain. Oh, and maybe think a bit about a chain isomorphic to $0<1<2<\ldots<\infty$ :)

Comment: Concerning the first question: Fields ;)

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain That does work :D Any others? :)

Comment: Of course there are more. For example $Z/p^nZ$ contains $n+1$ ideals in a chain for each prime $p$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Yes. The last challenge: do $-\infty<\ldots<-2<-1<0$ in a PID :) If you want to of course. And sorry for the digression.

Comment: Of course I want. Take $R:=\{x/y \in \mathbb{Q}\mid (x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2,2\nmid y\}$. I guess all ideals are of the form $(2^n)$ for some non-negative $n$. We have $(2^{n+1})\subset (2^n)$.

Comment: @principal-ideal-domain Yes. I asked a follow-up question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1086686/for-which-countable-successor-ordinals-alpha-is-the-reverse-order-isomorphic :)